# Looping through users to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to loop through my users who are managers and send them all an email, but I'm getting the following error:`undefined method "email" for nil:NilClass`. This is how I'm looping, which I think is the source of the issue:

```
def send_manager_email(current_user)
  managers = User.where(manager: true)
  managers.each do |manager|
    UserMailer.timesheet_notification(@manager, current_user).deliver_now
  end
end
```

and this is my mailer:

```
def timesheet_notification(user, current_user)
  @greeting = "Hi"
  @current_user = current_user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "New Timesheet"
end
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. You don't need `@manager`, You can only use `manager` when passing parameters.

```
def send_manager_email(current_user)
      managers = User.where(manager: true)
      managers.each do |manager|
        UserMailer.timesheet_notification(manager, current_user).deliver_now
      end
    end
```

and this is my mailer:

```
def timesheet_notification(user, current_user)
  @greeting = "Hi"
  @current_user = current_user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "New Timesheet"
end
```

Hope this will work for you. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that was foolish of me...thanks so much! Will accept asap.

Comment: Okay, No problem!. Please accept my answer. If it's working for you.